# pandas: Multi-level column dataframe - how to change the name for a specific level?

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas=1.1.5. For the 1st column, I want to change the top-level name.

**A 3-level column dataframe**

```
       | Revenue | Revenue |
       | Firm    |  GRP    |
       | Person  |  DIR    |
0      |  100    |  300    |
1      |  500    |  900    |
2      |  200    |  100    |
```

**Desired Outcome for Column[0] 3-level header columns**

```
-       |
Firm    |
Person  |
```

**Tried the below code, but nothing happened** Pls assist. Thank you

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: "-"}, level=0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I see is to get to MultiIndex, transfrom it to a list of list, apply the wanted changes and transform it backwards. The final step is to create a new MultiIndex.

```
m = [list(x) for x in df.columns]
m[0][0] = '-'
m  = [tuple(x) for x in m]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l)
```

To make this reusable you could create a function like this

```
# the nameing could be improved, because it is only working on columns
def rename_index_at_position(value, x, y):
    m = [list(x) for x in df.columns]
    m[x][y] = value
    m  = [tuple(x) for x in m]
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(m)
```

**Example**

Let's say we have a DataFrame df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100,300],[500,900],[200,100]], columns=[['Revenue','Revenue'] ,['Firm', 'GPR'],['Person', 'DIR']])

>>> df
  Revenue  Revenue
     Firm      GPR
   Person      DIR
0     100      300
1     500      900
2     200      100
```

Calling `df.columns = rename_index_at_position('-', 0, 0)` would give

```
>>>    - Revenue
    Firm     GPR
  Person     DIR
0    100     300
1    500     900
2    200     100
```

and `df.columns = rename_index_at_position('-', 1, 0)` returns

````
>>> df
  Revenue    -
     Firm  GPR
   Person  DIR
0     100  300
1     500  900
2     200  100
```

Of course you could also apply a new MultiIndex in the first place.
````